# Assigning an import to a variable within a constructor

Tags: facebook, typescript, import, ionic2

I am building an app in Ionic2. I want to implement Facebook within the app and so I am trying to use the ionic-native Facebook api. I imported it and then attempted to assign it to a variable so I could use the functions associated with it.

Here is my code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-news-feed',
  templateUrl: 'news-feed.html',
})
export class NewsFeed {

  fb: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, facebook: Facebook) {
    this.fb = facebook;
  }

    doRefresh(refresher) {
        console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Async operation has ended');
            refresher.complete();
        }, 2000);
    }

    this.fb.login([]);

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello NewsFeed Page');
  }

}
```

I thought an import works much like a class in that you can import it and assign it to a variable and then have access to its methods. Does it not work like that? How does it work?

Comment: It appears your call to `fb.login()` is outside of any function definition. Otherwise I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to import `Facebook` class like it is said in Ionic native docs :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/

You don't need to inject it through the constructor. As method are static this will print an error.

Be sure to also call `Facebook` after `platform.ready` event. And don't forget to add the plugin. See your example modified accordingly.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-news-feed',
  templateUrl: 'news-feed.html',
})
export class NewsFeed {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('Faceboook');
      Facebook.login([]).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    })
  }

    doRefresh(refresher) {
        console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Async operation has ended');
            refresher.complete();
        }, 2000);
    }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello NewsFeed Page');
  }

}
```